# Django manifest.json doesn't load icons

Tags: javascript, django, manifest, progressive-web-apps, audit

I've been trying to figure out how to load the icons from the manifest.json for Django.

```
{
  "short_name" : "Ct",
  "name"       : "CTAI",
  "icons"      : [
    {
      "src"    : "img/black.png",
      "type"   : "image/png",
      "sizes"  : "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url"  :"",
  "background_color" : "#ffffff",
  "display"    : "fullscreen",
  "theme_color": "#172435",
  "scope"      : "/",
  "orientation": "potrait"
}
```

and also the manifest settings for django in settings.py

```
PWA_APP_NAME = 'Ct'
PWA_APP_DESCRIPTION = "The dashboard for all you're needs."
PWA_APP_THEME_COLOR = '#172435'
PWA_APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#ffffff'
PWA_APP_DISPLAY = 'fullscreen'
PWA_APP_START_URL = '/'
PWA_APP_ICONS = [
    {
        'src':  '/black.png',
        'sizes': '512x512'
    }
]
```

However I get this error.

```
Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)
```

In the applications tab of the dev tools, the manifest.json seems to be a bit corrupted. The settings I've given and the settings here are completely different.
[The dev tools showing the manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQxjL.png)

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: I'm following [this](https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/convert-django-website-to-a-progressive-web-app-3536bc4f2862).

Comment: what package is this about? These aren't standard django settings

Comment: Please check the link i added.

Comment: did you solved??

Comment: @HemanthSP I had to remove this package since it didn't have much support from the author, the link is on my question.

Comment: Yes, the package seems to be outdated. I fixed the manifest.json issue but couldn't get the service worker to cache templates and load icon. I followed this guide: https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2020/Feb/29/django-pwa/